# How to increase the UICollectionView cell size while typing in textview (that is inside the cell)?

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

There is a textview in UICollectionView cell. I want the Cell to increase it's size while user is typing in it.

I tried setting estimatedSize to automatic size. Constraints are pinned to top/bottom/left/right and no height constraint. Textview is also set with no scroll, to make the text view to increase. But, unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried the same on UITableView and it works. Any kind of help is appreciated.